# iOS-Metal: How to clear Depth Buffer ? Similar to glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) in OpenGL

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, depth-buffer, metal

I need to clear the depth buffer, for which i use `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` in OpenGL, how to do in metal ? I have gone through apple's documentation, there is no hint about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that to clear the depth buffer you add these two lines before beginning a render pass:

`mRenderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;
mRenderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.clearDepth = 1.0f;`

And you **cannot** do a clear without ending and restarting a render pass.

Long answer:

In Metal, you have to define that you want the colour and depth buffers cleared when you start rendering to a `MTLTexture`. There is no clear function like in OpenGL.

To do this, in your `MTLRenderPassDescriptor`, set `depthAttachment.loadAction` to `MTLLoadActionClear` and `depthAttachment.clearDepth` to `1.0f`.
You may also want to set `colorAttachments[0].loadAction` to `MTLLoadActionClear` to clear the colour buffer.

This render pass descriptor is then passed in to your call to `MTLCommandBuffer::renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor`.

If you do want to clear a depth or colour buffer midway through rendering you have to call `endEncoding` on `MTLRenderCommandEncoder`, and then start encoding again with `depthAttachment.loadAction` set to `MTLLoadActionClear`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and precise answer muzza. I've explained with sample codes below.

Comment: it is impossible to understand that without seeing the code.

Comment: If you have got to this point, you already have a MTLRenderPassDescriptor, MTLCommandBuffer, renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor and endEncoding. Setting four parameters on your existing Descriptor is not really 'impossible to understand'

Comment: And to answer your previous comment (now deleted), Apple did not do it this way in order to make things '1400% more difficult for developers'. They did it because on tiled GPUs a clear operation is inherently linked to starting a render pass. Metal is all about keeping the code and hardware tied together and not hiding what is occurring behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the solution  more clear with sample codes

Before start rendering:

```
void prepareRendering(){
    CMDBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer]; // get command Buffer
    drawable = [_metalLayer nextDrawable]; // get drawable from metalLayer
    renderingTexture = drawable.texture; // set that as rendering te
    setupRenderPassDescriptorForTexture(drawable.texture); // set the depth and colour buffer properties
    RenderCMDBuffer = [CMDBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:_renderPassDescriptor];
    RenderCMDBuffer.label = @"MyRenderEncoder";
    setUpDepthState(CompareFunctionLessEqual,true,false); // 
    [RenderCMDBuffer setDepthStencilState:_depthState];
    [RenderCMDBuffer pushDebugGroup:@"DrawCube"];
}

void setupRenderPassDescriptorForTexture(id <MTLTexture> texture)
{
    if (_renderPassDescriptor == nil)
        _renderPassDescriptor = [MTLRenderPassDescriptor renderPassDescriptor];
        // set color buffer properties
        _renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = texture;
        _renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;
        _renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(1.0f, 1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f);
            _renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = MTLStoreActionStore;
// set depth buffer properties
            MTLTextureDescriptor* desc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat: MTLPixelFormatDepth32Float width: texture.width height: texture.height mipmapped: NO];
            _depthTex = [device newTextureWithDescriptor: desc];
            _depthTex.label = @"Depth";
            _renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.texture = _depthTex;
            _renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;
            _renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.clearDepth = 1.0f;
                _renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.storeAction = MTLStoreActionDontCare;
   }
```

Render Your contents here

```
Render();
```

After rendering

similar to ogles2 method   `[_context presentRenderbuffer:_colorRenderBuffer];`

```
void endDisplay()
{
    [RenderCMDBuffer popDebugGroup];
    [RenderCMDBuffer endEncoding];
    [CMDBuffer presentDrawable:drawable];
    [CMDBuffer commit];
    _currentDrawable = nil;
}
```

The above methods clears the depth and colour buffers after rendering each frame

To clear the depth buffer in midway

```
    void clearDepthBuffer(){
    // end encoding the render command buffer  
            [RenderCMDBuffer popDebugGroup];
            [RenderCMDBuffer endEncoding];

            // here MTLLoadActionClear will clear your last drawn depth values
            _renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;            _renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.clearDepth = 1.0f;
            _renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.storeAction = MTLStoreActionDontCare;

            // here MTLLoadActionLoad will reuse your last drawn color buffer
            _renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadActionLoad;
            _renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = MTLStoreActionStore;

            RenderCMDBuffer = [CMDBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:_renderPassDescriptor];
            RenderCMDBuffer.label = @"MyRenderEncoder";
            [RenderCMDBuffer pushDebugGroup:@"DrawCube"];
        }
```

Comment: how to do if you want to clear the color attachment but keep the depth buffer ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Swift 5 version. Run your first render pass:

```
        // RENDER PASS 1

        renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor

        if let renderPassDescriptor = renderPassDescriptor, let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) {

            renderEncoder.label = "First Render Encoder"
            renderEncoder.pushDebugGroup("First Render Debug")

            // render stuff here...

            renderEncoder.popDebugGroup()
            renderEncoder.endEncoding()
        }
```

Then clear the depth buffer, but keep the colour buffer:

```
        renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor

        // Schedule Metal to clear the depth buffer
        renderPassDescriptor!.depthAttachment.loadAction = MTLLoadAction.clear
        renderPassDescriptor!.depthAttachment.clearDepth = 1.0
        renderPassDescriptor!.depthAttachment.storeAction = MTLStoreAction.dontCare

        // Schedule Metal to reuse the previous colour buffer
        renderPassDescriptor!.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadAction.load
        renderPassDescriptor!.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = MTLStoreAction.store
```

Then run your second render:

```
        if let renderPassDescriptor = renderPassDescriptor, let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) {
           
            renderEncoder.label = "Second Render"
            renderEncoder.pushDebugGroup("Second Render Debug")

            // render stuff here...

            renderEncoder.popDebugGroup()
            renderEncoder.endEncoding()
        }
```